# Many sites in a WebRole : limits?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I know that we can have one WebRole for many sites using "Sites" section.
I'd like to know the limit of this : In which cases is it better to create a new WebRole ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation claims that you have "full IIS" - so the limits will be quite high - I've seen inside one shared hosting setup with well over a hundred sites running on the same IIS box.

At a practical level, the limits will depend on:

- how busy your individual sites are - how many resources each one requires in terms of network bandwidth, CPU, RAM, and disk space.
- how hard it's going to be to administer all your sites as one entity - it can be quite hard to synchronise the upgrade of multiple sites at a development team level, and it can generate additional testing (are you sure that upgrading site B hasn't changed sites A and C?)
- whether you want all your sites to scale together horizontally or whether you want to scale them independently.

Comment: Good answer.  The only other point is that Role (Web or Worker) is your unit of scale.  If you have a high volume site that is more likely to need to scale it probably a better idea to break it out on a different role so you can tune it's scale better.

Comment: +1 on scale units. Impacts customers, but also impacts you if you place your admin site along with dozens of customer sites chewing up all of the cpu and NIC bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks - updated the answer with points on "units of scale" and added "NIC bandwidth" sharing too